# Python reprint charcters from i's position to left (without ":" range)

Tags: python

Is it possbile to get:

ababbababa,babbababa,abbababa, bbababa,bababa,ababa,baba,aba,ba,a

using only loops with out ading additional [] to s2 and using ":"range

Currently I made it using loop:

```
s1="ababbababa" 
p1="aba"
s2=""

for i in range(len(s1)-1):
    for j in range(len(s1)-i):
        s2=s2+s1[i+j]
        print(s2)
        if(len(s2)==len(s2)):
            break
```

but it prints without in reversed order and to right: output gives me this: a
ab,aba,abab,ababb,ababba,ababbab,ababbaba,ababbabab, Thanks!

Comment: `if len(s2) == len(s2)` will always be `True`. Why do you have it there?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
a="ababbbbababab,abababa,abababb,aaba,abaaab,a"
print("".join([a[i-1] for i in range(len(a),0,-1)]))
```

Output:

```
a,baaaba,abaa,bbababa,abababa,babababbbbaba
```

Which is the same as:

```
rev = ""
for i in range(len(a),0,-1):
    rev += a[i-1]
print(rev)
```

But I think doing an internet search for "how to reverse a string python" would give ample resources for how to do this.